# Dependable dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a dependable drop down menu.

In my project each user are bound to single parent menu i.e. when a user sign in it will load only one parent menu and based on the single parent menu it will load 2 or 3 sub menu. This process is applicable to all other user's with different parent menu assigned for different users.

My problem is when a user is logged in he will have to click the single preloaded parent menu and it will load sub menu. But I want to load sub menu without clicking on the single preloaded parent menu.

PHP code for generating parent menu is

```
<select name="ddlstate"  id="ddlstate" class="ddlstate" style="width: 200px"  >
      <?php
       require('connect.php');           
        $list=mysql_query("select id,name from tbl_state where id='$region_session' ");
       while($row_list=mysql_fetch_array($list))
       {
        ?>

        <?php
        $id=$row_list['id'];
        $data=$row_list['name_en'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
        ?>     
</select>
```

Javascript code for generating submenu is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".ddlregion").focus(function()
    {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "menu_update.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $(".ddl_lbtype").html(html);

    } 
    });

    });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code waits for the page to be ready, then binds a function to the `focus` event of the element with class `ddlregion`.

It sounds like you don't want to wait for the `focus` event and instead run the function immediately.

All you have to do is take the function you are binding to the `focus` event and put it directly inside the call to `ready` (and replace `this` with the element of the menu).

I couldn't test this, since you didn't provide the HTML, but all I did was make the changes I mentioned and clean up the formatting. Hope it works!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id=$(".ddlregion").val(); 
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "menu_update.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $(".ddl_lbtype").html(html);
        } 
    });
});
```

Consider just sending the complete menu to the client or using `$.load` to bring in the HTML for the menu (assuming your API will allow a GET instead of a POST).